# Who created the Grand Priest?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In *Dragon Ball*, the Grand Priest is said to be the father of all the angels. But how about the Grand Priest? Was he created by Xeno or by someone else, or did he just simply always exist?

Answer (score 0):

During the Goku Black arc, we see Zeno destroy all the universes and is just floating in space.

My theory is that there is someone that created everything that just has not been figured out yet. Just like Beerus and Whis, Beerus is the destroyer god and Whis is the angel and the attendant for the destroyer. Well, the Grand Priest is the angel to the destroyer god Zeno (who is on a whole other scale from Beerus and other destroyers). And Zeno is made to destroy not create.

However, this is all a theory. And with the new upcoming arks such as the Moro ark and the Granola the Survivor arc, we may find out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Zeno did create somebody to provide the universes with peace, so maybe the Grand Priest decided to work on all the universes, but he must have created angels due to him getting tired. So maybe now the Grand Priest was the first angel that did not have a god of destruction.

My reasons are that the Grand Priest is:

1. maybe the first angel
2. a close person to Zeno

So he is probably the creation of Zeno as Zeno's first friend.